# How to disable forced redirects in magento

Tags: magento-1.8, redirect, ssl

I have enabled it in the Web category under system. I have lost my admin access due to the https problem so I would like to disable the forced redirect. Is there a way to do that using db or shell ?

Answer (score 3):

Disable URL redirect through shell:

```
echo "update core_config_data set value = 0 where path = 'web/url/redirect_to_base'" | mysql $MAGENTO_DB
n98-magerun cache:flush
```

Comment: Update: `magerun config:set web/url/redirect_to_base 0`

Answer (score 2):

> Removing var/session content will clear your customers sessions. So if you don't have any other choice this could be help you but with some disadvantages. This is why the solution is not recommande in a PRODUCTION environment.

#### This worked for me:

Start by removing all https from your config

```
UPDATE core_config_data
SET value=REPLACE(value, 'https', 'http') 
WHERE value LIKE 'https%';
```

Then remove the secure redirection

```
UPDATE core_config_data
SET value=0
WHERE path='web/secure/use_in_frontend' OR path='web/secure/use_in_adminhtml' OR path='web/url/redirect_to_base';
```

And **the most important after this**: delete content of

- var/cache
- var/full_page_cache
- var/session

Comment: Deleting `var/session` is never an appropiate solution. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94589/keeping-customers-logged-in-after-deleting-var-session

Comment: I understand this is an old response, however rather than deleting the cache run the you could run php bin/magento cache:flush after you run the SQL queries in the answer.

Comment: @NathanielR This is a Magento 1 question, there was no `bin/magento` commands.

Comment: You should not do this, there might be some third party modules which have entries which require https

Answer (score 1):

Go to your database and put your URL without https where path = web/unsecure/base_url and where path = web/secure/base_url.

Comment: I have done that already but still no use.

Comment: Clear cache manually, clear cookies and try with a different browser since the http to https redirect it might be cached at a browser level.

Comment: I have emptied var/cache. I have tried with other browsers now, but still same result

Comment: Is something in your .htaccess forcing you into SSL? Any other config you changed in the admin ?

Comment: I have Rewrite Engine as ON. Should I change this ?